# Is there a way to add a comment to a DHCP dynamic simple queue?

Tags: scripting, mikrotik

I simply want to add a comment (specifically, add the host name) to the simple queues created by the DHCP rate limit option.

However, while scripting, when I tried the command

```
/queue simple set dhcp-ds<XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX> comment="hello"
```

I was met with the error

```
failure: cannot change dynamic
```

Is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried `;`,  `#` or `//` on the same line before starting your comment?

Comment: @JohnGreene I'm not sure what you mean. I did try them as in `comment=";hello"`, no dice. If you meant it as like a code comment, it's not like that. A MikroTik queue has a bunch of settable parameters ([see screenshot](https://snipboard.io/Tix1LE.jpg)) such as `priority`, `max-limit`, and finally `comment`. I can set it just fine for my manually-created queues, but not queues created by the system automatically.